# Задействовать элементы кроме первого

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">ua</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">rus</a></li>
</ul>
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы первый элемент li не принимал класс active

Answer (score 1):

Один из множества вариантов

```js
$(document).on('click', 'ul > *:not(li:first-child)', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">ua</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">rus</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант нужен?

P.s. Лучше вещать обработчик на какой-то конкретный блок, а не на ul, ибо данный скрипт будет применяться ко всем.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.change-ul li:not(:first-child)', function() { 
  $('.change-ul li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="change-ul">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">ua</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">rus</a></li>
</ul>
```